# Get current clipping path from device handle (WinAPI)

Tags: winapi, gdi, clipping

I'm looking for a solution how to extract a current clipping path from a device handle (HDC) as a set of points (move to, line to, Bezier curves) with using WinAPI calls. For example, WinAPI allows to create complex clipping path with using AND, OR, XOR and DIFF logical operators and it can be used in different ways. For example, code below will creates three circles and merge it with some logic (mode1 and mode2):

```
void clippingTest(HDC dc, int x, int y, std::wstring const &text, int mode1, int mode2){
  SaveDC(dc);

  HBRUSH redBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 0, 0));
  HBRUSH greenBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 255, 0));
  HBRUSH blueBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 255));

  LOGFONT lf = {0};
  lf.lfHeight = -MulDiv(12, GetDeviceCaps(dc, LOGPIXELSY), 72);
  std::wstring const faceName = L"Arial";
  wcscpy_s(lf.lfFaceName, LF_FACESIZE, faceName.c_str());
  HFONT font = CreateFontIndirect(&lf);

  RECT rect = {x, y, x + 700, y + 650};
  FillRect(dc, &rect, greenBrush);

  BeginPath(dc);
    Ellipse(dc, x, y, x + 400, y + 400);
    //drawStar(dc, x, y);
  EndPath(dc);
  SelectClipPath(dc, RGN_COPY);

  BeginPath(dc);
    Ellipse(dc, x + 300, y, x + 700, y + 400);
    //drawStar(dc, x, y);
  EndPath(dc);
  SelectClipPath(dc, mode1);

  BeginPath(dc);
    Ellipse(dc, x + 150, y + 250, x + 550, y + 650);
    //drawStar(dc, x + 300, y);
  EndPath(dc);
  SelectClipPath(dc, mode2);

  SetPolyFillMode(dc, ALTERNATE);
  FillRect(dc, &rect, blueBrush);

  BeginPath(dc);
    Rectangle(dc, rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom);
  EndPath(dc);
  SelectClipPath(dc, RGN_COPY);

  SelectObject(dc, font);
  DrawText(dc, text.c_str(), text.length(), &rect, DT_CENTER | DT_TOP);

  RestoreDC(dc, -1);
}
```

[The result of clipping here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDte2.jpg)

And I'm interested in how to obtain the result path for further processing.

One of the solution can be drawing a clipping path on other HDC, create transparent image and use it for next drawing. But this approach will increase the result file (PDF, for example).

Answer (score 0):

Have found a solution which allows to approximate the result area with rectangles.

```
  void Emf2PdfEngine::selectClippingPath(void){
    Rgn rgn(CreateRectRgn(0, 0, 1, 1)); // RAII for HRGN object
    if (!GetClipRgn(mHdc, rgn))
      return;

    DWORD const rgnSize = GetRegionData(rgn, 0, nullptr);
    std::vector<uint8_t> rgnData(rgnSize);
    GetRegionData(rgn, rgnSize, (RGNDATA *) rgnData.data());
    RGNDATA *rawData = (RGNDATA *) rgnData.data();

    uint32_t const count = rawData->rdh.nCount; // count of RECT objects
    if (!count)
      return;

    mCurrentDeviceState->mIsClipped = true;
    mCurrentDeviceState->mClippingPathPoints.resize(count * 2);
    mCurrentDeviceState->mClippingPathTypes.resize(count * 2);

    RECT *rect = (RECT *) rawData->Buffer;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i){
      mCurrentDeviceState->mClippingPathPoints[i * 2] = {rect[i].left, rect[i].top};
      mCurrentDeviceState->mClippingPathPoints[i * 2 + 1] = {rect[i].right - rect[i].left, rect[i].bottom - rect[i].top};
      mCurrentDeviceState->mClippingPathTypes[i * 2] = PT_RECT;
      mCurrentDeviceState->mClippingPathTypes[i * 2 + 1] = PT_RECT;// | PT_CLOSEFIGURE;
    }
  }
```